# error: not found: value sqlContext

Tags: apache-spark

I would like to create a python application to analyze twitter streaming data using Apache Spark.

Is there any way I can use the functionality of Apache Spark streaming without setting up the Hadoop environment. How to run Apache Spark in standalone mode?
I just downloaded the binaries and tried to run spark-shell, getting NullPointerException. Can someone please help.

```
<console>:10: error: not found: value sqlContext
import sqlContext.implicits.

<console>:10: error: not found: value sqlContext
import sqlContext.sql
```

Comment: First, this question has nothing to do with twitter analysis, so don't use misleading titles in your questions. Secondly, spark-shell isn't for python, so I'm not sure what you are trying to do

Comment: I am new to Data field, just exploring the Apache Spark, trying to do some simple analysis using spark streaming in windows platform without setting up the Hadoop environment.

Comment: Ok but still your question has nothing to do with that! Indeed you don't need to set up hadoop to use spark, but getting an error about using a variable isn't related to data analysis. Do you agree with that? Still to know what's your problem because as I said, it's not clear to me. Which shell are you using? what are you doing to get such error? etc...

Comment: you are right. Just setting up the environment for spark. I don't have any idea about shell, I found some spark related video in You tube, they used spark-shell and tried the same in my machine, I got this SQL context error, So i thought something I missed in installation. For data analysis using standalone server, i don't have any direction right now., if you find any resource, please do share.

Comment: Try to start with the beginning then, the Spark official documentation is great actually for this purpose ;)

Answer (score 3):

I install spark 1.5.2 using homebrew, and when I started the spark-shell, I met the same error. I add export SPARK_LOCAL_IP=127.0.0.1 to .bashrc or .bash_profile. It Works.

Answer (score 1):

If you work with Spark 1.6, Linux/Unix and if you find the following lines in the error message:

```
 ...
 java.net.UnknownHostException: <YOURHOSTNAME>: <YOURHOSTNAME>: unknown error at
 java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1663)
 ...
 Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: <YOURHOSTNAME>: unknown error    
 ...
 <console>:16: error: not found: value sqlContext
                import sqlContext.sql
```

add in /etc/hosts:

```
 $ sudo vi /etc/hosts
 ...
 127.0.0.1  <YOURHOSTNAME>
 ...
```

This solved in my case the missing sqlContext value problem.